# Как реализовать смену url после ajax запроса?

Tags: javascript

Допустим мы находимся на странице **www.site/feed** на этой странице есть `<div class="main"></div>` в котором находится контент. На странице так же есть кнопка которая выполняет ajax запрос на страницу **user.php** и результат выводит в **.main**. Мы по прежнему находимся на странице *www.site/feed* но с помощью `js window.history.pushState`, меняем ссылку на **user**. Собственно проблема в том, что если после смены url нажать стрелку "назад" в браузере то контент не меняется.

Например в **.main** было `content content....`
И после ajax ссылка сменилась на **user** и контент в **.main** стал например `res res...`
Теперь если в браузере мы вернемся на пред ссылку то ссылка измениться на **feed** но контент останется.
Как сделать так, что бы и контент тоже обновился ?

Answer (score 0):

Надо подписаться на событие `popstate` и в обработчике вывести желаемый контент. Оно вызовется при нажатии back.